# Pandas conditional statement with NaT

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

So, I have a dataframe with many variables. The index is uid and the other variables are all dates.

I am trying to create flag variables when a certain value is NaT but I can't find the correct statement.

I want something like this:

```
auxData['flagInvited'] = np.where(auxData['invited'] == NaT, 0, 1)
```

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) for convert to `boolean mask` and then cast to `int` - `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`:

```
auxData['flagInvited'] = auxData['invited'].notnull().astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
auxData = pd.DataFrame({'invited':[np.nan, '2017-01-01','2017-03-03']})
auxData.invited = pd.to_datetime(auxData.invited, dayfirst=True)
print (auxData)
     invited
0        NaT
1 2017-01-01
2 2017-03-03

print (auxData['invited'].notnull())
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: invited, dtype: bool

auxData['flagInvited'] = auxData['invited'].notnull().astype(int)
print (auxData)
     invited  flagInvited
0        NaT            0
1 2017-01-01            1
2 2017-03-03            1
```

Comment: If I may ask you one last thing, when I do a subtraction between 2 datetime variables how can i return the result as number of days?

Comment: sure, you need `print ((df['date1'] - df['date2']).dt.days)` if need output as `int`